# Sorting du -h accounting for decimals

Tags: bash, du

I have done `du -h /path`, which gives me a line with the following syntax:

```
size path
size path
size path
```

I want to sort the lines of the file based on size. The problem is that size can contain decimal values, like `9.4G`. If I apply `sort -hr` it gives me a weird sorting like:

```
444G    path
326G    path
9.4G    path
9.4G    path
8.3G    path
8.2G    path
7.8G    path
74G     path
7.4G    path
7.3G    path
```

So I guess the problem is that the decimals are being, ignored? I think 74G appears below 7.8G because `sort` is interpreting it as `78G`. How can I solve this problem? (it looks like it has something to do with locales).

**NOTE:** I use git-bash.

Comment: Why are you using `-h` then?

Comment: To account for `G`, `M`, `K`, etc, but for some reasons it gets confused with the dot.

Comment: `-h` tells `du` to choose a suitable unit for you, and you end up having different units for each line, some of them containing fractional values, which `sort` can't handle. If you don't give an option, you just get the plain integer figures without any character at the hand, and sorting becomes trivial, because you don't have decimals in them.

Comment: Can you try `LC_ALL=C sort -hr` ?

Comment: I use git bash and for some reason in-line exports does not work, so if I write LC_ALL=C the env change won't be seen by `sort`.

Comment: @ABu How are you testing that? (Remember, `foo=old; foo=new echo "$foo"` echos `old` even in a version of bash where in-line exports work perfectly -- you need to do something more like `foo=new env | grep foo` to have a valid test).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tested it some time ago with makefiles, where I changed an env var and within a makefile I printed its value with $(info) (like `CXX=something make`). Then I opened an MSYS2 terminal and it worked. I think I do some testings with a bash script containing an `echo $SOME_ENV_VAR` but I'm not sure about that second test. So maybe is not something of git bash but my own settings? Not sure.

Comment: @ABu, ...mind, you can certainly use `(export LC_ALL=C; exec sort -hr)` in a pipeline (the `exec` consumes the subshell created with the parens, to which the export is scoped) to avoid needing the syntax.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice trick, thank you, I will try it later.

Comment: This is working fine in my Git Bash. Is it persistent? Does `sort` give you the same results if you put the data in a file and `sort` that?

Comment: BTW, one way I think I've seen people handle this in the past is not to use `-h`, but instead to have awk convert into the more human-friendly numbers _after_ sort is done.

Comment: @PaulHodges the data is actually already in a file. The `du -h` has been executed on a server, the output redirected to a file, the file downloaded to my local machine and the sort execute in the local machine. Sorting in the server works as expected, but in my local machine with git bash doesn't. And LC_ALL=C changes nothing.

Comment: Is `sort -hr` on the server showing differently ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, it sorts the lines correctly.

Comment: I've finally reproduce you're output by copying them as input to `LANG=de_DE sort -hr` !!
This is clearly a *language* problem.